# Using awk to find a domain name containing the longest repeated word

Tags: regex, bash, awk

For example, let's say there is a file called `domains.csv` with the following:

```
1,helloguys.ca
2,byegirls.com
3,hellohelloboys.ca
4,hellobyebyedad.com
5,letswelcomewelcomeyou.org
```

I'm trying to use linux awk regex expressions to find the line that contains the longest repeated<sup>1</sup> word, so in this case, it will return the line

```
5,letswelcomewelcomeyou.org
```

How do I do that?

<sup>1</sup> Meaning "immediately repeated", i.e., `abcabc`, but not `abcXabc`.

Comment: What if there are more than one longest repeated word? (the first, the last, all of them?)

Comment: I guess all of them!

Comment: The first problem is how to find the longest repeated substring for one record, imagine you have something like "bbwelcomewelcome", since a regex engine work from left to right, a basic pattern will find "bb".

Comment: maybe store the first repeated substring into a variable and if it finds another substring within the same string that has a longer repeated substring, then overwrite the first first substring with the new one?

Comment: Does "repeated" mean "immediately next to each other", or can there be characters between the repetitions, as in `welcomeblahwelcome`?

Comment: repeated means "immediately next to each other"

Comment: I've added that to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pure awk implementation would be rather long-winded as awk regexes don't have backreferences, the usage of which simplifies the approach quite a bit.

I'ved added one line to the example input file for the case of multiple longest words:

```
1,helloguys.ca
2,byegirls.com
3,hellohelloboys.ca
4,hellobyebyedad.com
5,letswelcomewelcomeyou.org
6,letscomewelcomewelyou.org
```

And this gets the lines with the longest repeated sequence:

```
cut -d ',' -f 2 infile | grep -Eo '(.*)\1' |
awk '{ print length(), $0 }' | sort -k 1,1 -nr |
awk 'NR==1 {prev=$1;print $2;next} $1==prev {print $2;next} {exit}' | grep -f - infile
```

Since this is pretty anti-obvious, let's split up what this does and look at the output at each stage:

1. Remove the first column with the line number to avoid matches for lines numbers with repeating digits:

   ```
   $ cut -d ',' -f 2 infile
   helloguys.ca
   byegirls.com
   hellohelloboys.ca
   hellobyebyedad.com
   letswelcomewelcomeyou.org
   letscomewelcomewelyou.org
   ```
2. Get all lines with a repeated sequence, extract just that repeated sequence:

   ```
   ... | grep -Eo '(.*)\1'
   ll
   hellohello
   ll
   byebye
   welcomewelcome
   comewelcomewel
   ```
3. Get the length of each of those lines:

   ```
   ... | awk '{ print length(), $0 }'
   2 ll
   10 hellohello
   2 ll
   6 byebye
   14 welcomewelcome
   14 comewelcomewel
   ```
4. Sort by the first column, numerically, descending:

   ```
   ...| sort -k 1,1 -nr
   14 welcomewelcome
   14 comewelcomewel
   10 hellohello
   6 byebye
   2 ll
   2 ll
   ```
5. Print the second of these columns for all lines where the first column (the length) has the same value as on the first line:

   ```
   ... | awk 'NR==1{prev=$1;print $2;next} $1==prev{print $2;next} {exit}'
   welcomewelcome
   comewelcomewel
   ```
6. Pipe this into grep, using the `-f -` argument to read stdin as a file:

   ```
   ... | grep -f - infile
   5,letswelcomewelcomeyou.org
   6,letscomewelcomewelyou.org
   ```

**Limitations**

While this can handle the `bbwelcomewelcome` case mentioned in comments, it will trip on overlapping patterns such as `welwelcomewelcome`, where it only finds `welwel`, but not `welcomewelcome`.

**Alternative solution with more awk, less `sort`**

As pointed out by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in comments, this can be simplified to skip the `sort` step and combine the two awk steps and the `sort` step into a single awk step, likely improving performance:

```
$ cut -d ',' -f 2 infile | grep -Eo '(.*)\1' |
awk '{if (length()>ml) {ml=length(); delete a; i=1} if (length()>=ml){a[i++]=$0}}
END{for (i in a){print a[i]}}' |
grep -f - infile
```

Let's look at that awk step in more detail, with expanded variable names for clarity:

```
{
    # New longest match: throw away stored longest matches, reset index
    if (length() > max_len) {
        max_len = length()
        delete arr_longest
        idx = 1
    }

    # Add line to longest matches
    if (length() >= max_len)
        arr_longest[idx++] = $0
}

# Print all the longest matches
END {
    for (idx in arr_longest)
        print arr_longest[idx]
}
```

**Benchmarking**

I've timed the two solutions on the [top one million domains file](http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip) mentioned in the comments:

- First solution (with `sort` and two awk steps):

  ```
  964438,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com

  real    1m55.742s
  user    1m57.873s
  sys     0m0.045s
  ```
- Second solution (just one awk step, no `sort`):

  ```
  964438,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com

  real    1m55.603s
  user    1m56.514s
  sys     0m0.045s
  ```
- And the [Perl solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35421783/3266847) by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte):

  ```
  964438,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk.com

  real    0m5.249s
  user    0m5.234s
  sys     0m0.000s
  ```

What we learn from this: ask for a Perl solution next time ;)

Interestingly, if we know that there will be just one longest match and simplify the commands accordingly (just `head -1` instead of the second awk command for the first solution, or no keeping track of multiple longest matches with awk in the second solution), the time gained is only in the range of a few seconds.

**Portability remark**

Apparently, BSD grep can't do `grep -f -` to read from stdin. In this case, the output of the pipe until there has to be redirected to a temp file, and this temp file then used with `grep -f`.

Answer (score 6):

A way with perl:

```
perl -F, -ane 'if (@m=$F[1]=~/(?=(.+)\1)/g) {
    @m=sort { length $b <=> length $a} @m;
    $cl=length @m[0];
    if ($l<$cl) { @res=($_); $l=$cl; } elsif ($l==$cl) { push @res, ($_); }
}
END { print @res; }' file
```

The idea is to find all longest overlapping repeated strings for each position in the second field, then the match array is sorted and the longest substring becomes the first item in the array (`@m[0]`).

Once done, the length of the current repeated substring (`$cl`) is compared with the stored length (of the previous longest substring). When the current repeated substring is longer than the stored length, the result array is overwritten with the current line, when the lengths are the same, the current line is pushed into the result array.

details:

command line option:

`-F,` set the field separator to `,`
`-ane` (`e` execute the following code, `n` read a line at a time and puts its content in `$_`, `a` autosplit, using the defined FS, and puts fields in the `@F` array)

The pattern:

```
/
(?=         # open a lookahead assertion
    (.+)\1  # capture group 1 and backreference to the group 1
)           # close the lookahead
/g # all occurrences
```

This is a well-know pattern to find all overlapping results in a string. The idea is to use the fact that a lookahead doesn't consume characters (a lookahead only means *"check if this subpattern follows at the current position"*, but it doesn't match any character). To obtain the characters matched in the lookahead, all that you need is a capture group.
Since a lookahead matches nothing, the pattern is tested at each position (and doesn't care if the characters have been already captured in group 1 before).

Comment: Is this expecting a space somewhere? The real input file doesn't have spaces after the comma. I wanted to benchmark this to compare to my solutions.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: indeed, after archeological research I found the file (without spaces).

Comment: See benchmarking. This is an order of magnitude faster than mine ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Whao, the difference is impressive! But the most important thing is that your computer is faster than mine.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Just a thought, it would be awesome and a great learning experience if you can explain what each line (or parts within each line) does! 
Especially the first line: perl -F, -ane 'if (@m=$F[1]=~/(?=(.+)\1)/g)